# Fill the layout with variable count of TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, textview

I need to show the TextViews based on the info received from a server. E.g. I got 7 words from the server . I need to put every word in a different TextView to make it clickable. The textviews should fill the screen of the device from left to right in the lines. When the right border is reached then the next TextViews should be placed on the next line and so on. 
The quantity of TextViews is variable and the words in the Textviews is different as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
I won't put the whole code here. Only main parts. 
There is vertical LinearLayout. 
We need to calculate the width of the layout. I couldn't do it because I do all calculations before it is drawed. 
I'm getting the screen width in dips:

```
    Display display = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
    int displayWidth = (int) dpWidth;
```

This is the free space available to put the Textviews.
Add LinearLayout to parent. Create a Textview and calculate the width:

```
    // Calculate size of the button
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = menuCategoryTV.getPaint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    int width = bounds.width();
```

Then check if there is a room to place the Textview in the layout. To get it deduct TextView's width from available free space on the screen. Of course there is a space for the first textView. Until your TextView is not very long. But after filling up the layout by TextViews there will be no room for new elements. Create new LinearLayout, add it to parent and reset availble room to initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Create new textView instance and setLayoutparams to them.

Example,

```
TextView[] tx = new TextView[10];
    TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[10];
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        tx[i] = new TextView(this);
        tx[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tx[i].setText("Data")
        tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
        tr[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr[i].addView(tx[i]);
        // and then adding table row in tablelayout
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you can use single textview and set spannable string to the textview.
Within that string you can provide clicks you want.

Comment: I'm using drawable resource for TextViews. I didn't found how to use it with Spannable